# Reading json file from remote url in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

Suppose Some JSON file is @  www.github.com/xyz/Hello.json, I want to read this content of this JSON in JSON object in Groovy

Answer (score 1):

You then need:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parse('www.github.com/xyz/Hello.json'.toURL())
```

[Here](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html#json_jsonslurper) you can find more info.

Comment: I want to read the json in  json object ..


www.github.com/xyz/Hello.json 

Hello.json  = { "name" = "xyz" , "age" = "25 "

}

@Opal
slurped  = { "name" = "xyz" , "age" = "25 " }  ???